# Live Stream stops playing on Google TV & Motorola Xoom Tablet in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, live-streaming, google-tv

I am sorry if i am posting same question twice... but i am desperate and badly stuck.

I am creating an Android app which will be deployed on Google TV devices & Tablets initially.. My Android application plays live streams of different TV channels.

Channel's Stream Info is:

**Codec:** H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (i determined the CODEC info by playing the stream in VLC player)
**Stream url:** starts with **rtsp://**

I haved used the **[VideoPlayer_demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html)** example, presented on Android developer site, with some changes to load stream asynchronously and catch errors.

I have checked my app on **Logitech** Google TV device & **Motorola Xoom tablet** and the issue is on both.

Both devices begin playing stream properly.. then hangs for a few seconds and then begins playing it (*i think its downloading the stream???*) .. it does this two/three times and then hangs completely. And the video does not play at all.

Our servers also provide streams in **Windows Media Video 9 (WMV3)** format ... but it was not working at all. I think this format is not supported on Google TV/Android.

Please help me fix this issue OR tell me an alternate way to do so.

**Edit:**

LogCat does not show any error. The only warnings it shows are as follows:

```
01-19 13:32:13.319: W/MediaPlayer(678): info/warning (701, 0)
01-19 13:32:13.328: I/MediaPlayer(678): Info (701,0)
01-19 13:32:15.428: W/MediaPlayer(678): info/warning (702, 0)
01-19 13:32:15.428: I/MediaPlayer(678): Info (702,0)
01-19 13:47:26.148: D/MediaPlayerDemo(678): onCompletion called
```

The last line is a bit suspicious as it recorded in the **onCompletion** event of **MediaPlayer** which is called when the end of a media source is reached during playback. I think this event shows that the **MediaPlayer** has considered the video to have finished, and after this event the video stops playing.

I have uploaded a small demo project **[here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=e59127ff3955f781&resid=E59127FF3955F781!111&parid=E59127FF3955F781!109&authkey=!APF1aOoBm4XeMeI)** that tries to stream a demo live TV. Its link is in the Project. This demo also hangs and causes the same problem. So by running this demo on your tablet/google tv device, you would know exactly what issue i am facing.

Thanks

Comment: do you see anything in the logs? could you paste them here. Also provide a demo url to test this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question and provided a small demo with the link to the stream in it. I thought showing you exactly what i am doing may help you understand the problem.

Comment: @Megha Joshi ... any update??? i am totally depending upon u & ur colleague Les ... i already have sent an email to google-tv-fishtank-team (at) googlegroups dot com describing my situation with a demo URL .. please help

Answer (score 0):

I also have exactly the same problem. I think the problem is not around the type of streaming.

I have the same problem on Wifi/Ethernet and http/rtmp/smb streamings. I even download the file and copied it to the memory and still the file stops when playing. That file plays correctly on http streaming by Windows/VLC Media players.

I think this is codec or file container problem. My file has the following header:    ftypmp42    isommp42 )moov   lmvhd

A sample file can be found in the following location:

http://marjaaftp.http.internapcdn.net/MARJAAFTP/Images/GMAAssets/Video/299.mov

Comment: Thanks. It was a question i asked quite some time ago. Later we shifted to using HLS streams and it works fine on both.